# What's the relation between Germanic suffixes -ly, -lich, -lijk, ... and Turkic suffixes -lik -liq

Tags: indo-european, germanic-languages, turkish, turkic-languages

What's the relation between Germanic adjectival/adverbial suffixes

> -ly, -lich, -lijk, ...

and Turkic suffixes

> -lik -liq

that convert nouns/adjectives to nouns

Answer (score 8):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/_lich) and other sources state that -lich is a grammaticalized form of the Middle High German līch ["body"] (which also gave rise to Leiche). -ly, -lich, -lijk (and Scandinavian forms) are actually all of similar derivation and converge to a single Germanic ancestral suffix ([see discussion on details here](http://books.google.de/books?id=76UUIcCqMYkC&pg=PA155)).

The Turkic -lik appeared already in the Old Turkic times and probably was related to a similar in form and meaning Mongolian suffix ([see e.g. here](http://journals.istanbul.edu.tr/iuturkiyat/article/download/1023009437/pdf)).

So, a hypothesis about common ancestry of the Germanic and the Turkic suffixes via borrowing is at least non-parsimonious. (Not to mention, that there are no genetic links between these two groups of languages.)

Comment: I thought there was no consensus that Turkic and Mongolic are related at all. There are definitely influences due to being neighbours though.

Comment: @hippietrail: "related" in this context means "could have been borrowed".